# Rxjs mouse events not retrieving mouse coordinates

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to catch all the mouse coordinates using 'mousemove'.

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';    

export class numbersThrower {
  static numbersGo() {
    const obs$ = fromEvent(document,'mousemove');
    obs$.pipe(
      throttleTime(10000)
    )
    return obs$;
  }
}

const obs$ = numbersThrower.numbersGo();

obs$.subscribe(
  (data)=>console.log(data)
)
```

This is what I get: MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, constructor: Object}

Why aren't there the screenX and screenY properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your issue, console does not shows the complete Event object.I am assuming you are trying your code in any online editor.

It does not happens in local development environment.

I have faced such issue in stackblitz but you can still access the screenX and screenY position by specifying the respective event type.

```
obs$.subscribe(
  (data:MouseEvent)=>console.log(data.screenX, data.screenY)
)
```